# Into "particle edit" to make brush fur,but it didn't works

Tags: particles

I use particle to make fur, but when I almost finish, I go into "particle edit". I can't brush my fur?[image]

Comment: Do you have more than one hair particle system on the object? Because usually when you go to _Particle Edit_, the hair strands should show in black, while yours look like they are still in _Object Mode_. But I see no other black hair particles in the screenshot. So either you have selected the wrong object before switching to _Particle Edit_ or you have the selected the wrong particle system. But more is hard to say without seeing any of your settings, modifiers etc.